# ASP.NET omit specific variable in response?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

In ApiController subclass,

```
[HttpGet]
public HttpResponseMessage api()
{
 //somecode 
 Res res = new Res();
 return Request.CreateResponse(200, res);

}
```

And Res class,

```
public class Res{
Public Meta meta{get;set;}
Public Data data{get;set;}
}
```

In case of some http status code such as 401, 500, I want to omit data variable.

200 ok

```
{ meta:{...}, data:{...}}
```

500 internal server error 
    { meta:{...}}

How to omit data variable? remove variable in class?
use ExpandoObject()?

Comment: What if you set `data` as `null`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use:

```
public class Res{

    Public Meta meta{get;set;}

    [JsonIgnore]
    Public Data data{get;set;}
}
```

Or, decorate the ones you want...

```
[DataContract]
public class Res{

    [DataMember]  
    Public Meta meta{get;set;}

    Public Data data{get;set;}
}
```